# customized spinning progress indicator for Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsprogressindicator

I want to implement a customized spinning progress indicator over a Webview, I have seen small and regular indicator but I need to implement my own customized indicator like size of indicator would be big one.

I need to hide and make it visible in  different scenarious, This should spin over webview.

Comment: @JoshCaswell,I know how to use normal indicators but I am facing problem to spin this over the webview.

Comment: Your question reads as asking for the complete procedure for a new UI element. That's not what Stack Overflow is for. If you've tried something and are stuck on a specific point, then please add that to your question.